# C# - Deserialize JSON string into Class

Tags: c#, json

I'm very new to C# so please excuse me if if i am asking stupid question.
I'm using Newtownsoft JSON (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Here is my class:

```
public class CharacterData
{
    public int characterId;
    public int connectionId;
    public int accountId;
    public string name;
    public int level;
    public int characterRace;
    public int characterClass;
    public CharacterPosition characterPosition;
    public CharacterRotation characterRotation;
    public CharacterInstance charactrerInstance;
    public CharacterState characterState;
    public CharacterMovementState characterMovementState;
    public CharacterActionState characterActionState;
    public CharacterEmotionState characterEmotionState;
    public string lastOnline;
    public string onlineTime;
}

public class CharacterPosition
{
    public string x;
    public string y;
    public string z;
    public int map; //Map id
}
public class CharacterInstance
{
    public int instanceId;
    public int groupId;
}
public class CharacterRotation
{
    public string x;
    public string y;
    public string z;
}

public class CharacterLearnedSpells
{
    public int spellId;
}

public enum CharacterState
{
    Alive,
    Dead,
    Ghost
}

public enum CharacterMovementState
{
    Standing,
    Walking,
    Running,
    Jumping,
}

public enum CharacterActionState
{
    Idle,
    Attacking,
    Casting,
}

public enum CharacterEmotionState
{
    Idle,
    Speaking,
    Questioning,
    Exclamating,
    Dancing,
    Insulting,
    Attacking,

}
```

Here is my json string:

```
{
    "1":
        {
            "characterId": 1,
            "connectionId": 1,
            "accountId": 1,
            "name": "Riorage",
            "level": 2,
            "characterRace": 1,
            "characterClass": 1,
            "characterPosition": {
                "x": "15.42661",
                "y": "7.477493",
                "z": "-32.30045",
                "map": 1

            },
            "characterRotation": {
                "x": "1",
                "y": "203",
                "z": "1"

            },
            "charactrerInstance": {
                "instanceId": 0,
                "groupId": 0

            },
            "characterState": 1,
            "characterMovementState": 0,
            "characterActionState": 1,
            "characterEmotionState": 1,
            "lastOnline": "5.4.2018 г. 14:59:16",
            "onlineTime": "1"
        }
}
```

Here is how i try to parse this json into my `Characterdata` class:

```
public void SpawnPlayer(Dictionary<string, string> playerData, int cnnId)    
{
    Debug.Log("Spawning..");
    CharacterData charData = new CharacterData();


    foreach (var item in playerData)
    {
        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Value, Formatting.None);
        Debug.Log(jsonData);
        charData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CharacterData>(jsonData);
    }
}
```

However this is not working.

Here is what error i receive:

```
ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to CharacterData.
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable (System.Object value, System.Type initialType, System.Type targetType) (at C:/Project/Github/Json.Net.Unity3D/src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ConvertUtils.cs:668)
```

Can you help me out achieve what i want ?
I want to deserialize this JSON string into the class `CharacterData`. Is it even possible ?

Comment: **However this is not working** - what exactly is wrong? Please be precise.

Comment: I have added the error.

Comment: You're calling `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` on a `string` - `item.Value` is a string. Is that what you actually want to do? And then you deserialize the serialized string... I can't even

Comment: not a valid json string (even after fixing the \r\n and \")

Comment: @MattJones as i said im new to this.

Comment: you seem to have a json string that has json inside it

if i remove {"1":"    and at the end  "}  its a valid string fyi

Comment: You're serialising a string and then trying to deserialise it into your class - that's where it's wrong. What does the playerData actually hold? It looks like it's already serialised.

Comment: i havent even looked at your code yet.  your JSON is not valid

Comment: How are you generating your data?  As others have noted, you don't have valid json.  What's the value of `playerData` when you pass it in to the `SpawnPlayer` function?

Comment: @abr The invalid json is a key part of this question.  If the poster were dealing with valid json, they wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: @MunimMunna You shouldn't have approved that edit; it renders the question meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your json, fixed with the "\", \r\n and stuf. For future references, please post the correct json.

```
{
    "1":
        {
            "characterId": 1,
            "connectionId": 1,
            "accountId": 1,
            "name": "Riorage",
            "level": 2,
            "characterRace": 1,
            "characterClass": 1,
            "characterPosition": {
                "x": "15.42661",
                "y": "7.477493",
                "z": "-32.30045",
                "map": 1

            },
            "characterRotation": {
                "x": "1",
                "y": "203",
                "z": "1"

            },
            "charactrerInstance": {
                "instanceId": 0,
                "groupId": 0

            },
            "characterState": 1,
            "characterMovementState": 0,
            "characterActionState": 1,
            "characterEmotionState": 1,
            "lastOnline": "5.4.2018 г. 14:59:16",
            "onlineTime": "1"
        }
}
```

What I think you should do is:

1. Start by creating a class with the same structure as your json

(I'll post this example and you can set up the other classes and fields)

```
public class CharacterData
{
    [JsonProperty("characterId")] //if you want to reference the field coming in the json, this will allow you to have different name on the property below.
    public int characterId; 
    public int connectionId;
    public int accountId;
    public string name;
    public int level;
    public int characterRace;
    public int characterClass;
    public CharacterPosition characterPosition;
    public CharacterRotation characterRotation;
    public CharacterInstance charactrerInstance;
    public CharacterState characterState;
    public CharacterMovementState characterMovementState;
    public CharacterActionState characterActionState;
    public CharacterEmotionState characterEmotionState;
    public string lastOnline;
    public string onlineTime;
}
```

Depending on how you're getting your json, you can retrieve it from some connection or from some string, but be advised that the json must be properly formatted

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CharacterData>(YourJsonStringOrResponseHere);

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CharacterData>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it obligatory to have `[JsonProperty("jsonKey")]` field above all variables in the class ?

Comment: Not really (been a while since I last touched c#) but definitely can help you by maintaining your code (name of the properties) to your liking and not restricted to whatever comes from the request

Comment: If you did, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point for me was to look online for some online sites that do just that.  ie JSON to C# class.  Try this: http://json2csharp.com/

It helped me quite a bit.

Comment: although this is a tool, it is not his answer

Comment: I know it's not the answer to the question directly, but it might help to reverse engineer the tool's answer, act as a pointer to why he's having this problem.  And if the JSON is invalid (replacing \" with " and \r\n with nothing) is invalid JSON as @MichaelEvanchik points out, then not even the online tool will help.